# clojure type conversion string to symbol

Tags: clojure

in clojure i have vector ["myfn1" "myfn2" "myfn3"]
how can i call functions named "myfn1" ... using strings from that vector

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To call a function bound to Var `myfn1` given the string `"myfn1"`, you could do something like this:

```
((resolve (symbol "myfn1")) ...) ; ... indicates where to put any arguments
```

So, given your example vector and assuming that you don't need to pass any additional arguments to your functions (it's straighforward enough to modify this code if you do), you could do the following:

```
(map #((resolve (symbol %))) ["myfn1" "myfn2" "myfn3"])
```

E.g.

```
user=> (map #((resolve (symbol %1)) %2) ["println" "print" "prn"] ["asdf" "asdf" "asdf"])
(asdf
asdfnil "asdf"
nil nil)
```

(The `nil`s are the return values from the printing functions; note how there's no linebreak after the `asdf` produced by `print` and the `asdf` produces by `prn` is quoted.)